# Typescript: Index type not working in a conditional if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having some trouble with understanding indexed typing in a conditional situation. I have set up a function below that will accept a `profile` object and apply the provided value to its `settings` with the provided key. No problem! The issue is if I want to handle a simple use case for one of those settings, in this case, I want to perform an arithmetic operation on `settingThree` which is clearly defined as a number in the `Settings` interface. The compiler however does not like it and complains that:

> *`An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`*

**Below is my example**

```
interface Settings {
    settingOne: boolean;
    settingTwo: string[];
    settingThree: number;
}

interface Profile {
    id: number;
    settings: Settings;
}

function setSettings<SN extends keyof Settings>(
    profile: Profile,
    settingName: SN,
    settingData: Settings[SN]
) {
    if(profile.settings && profile.settings[settingName]) {
        profile.settings[settingName] = settingData;

        /**
         * Error is thrown here, settingData++ is identified as the cause of this error
         * An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
         */
        if (settingName === "settingThree") settingData++; 
    }
}
```

**A solution** I have been able to use is by explicitly typing out

```
if (settingName === "settingThree") (settingData as number)++;
```

This is fine and I'm happy to use this, **however**, I am curious as to why this would be necessary?
Is the type not clearly inferred by the condition? How could `settingData` be anything other than a `number` type at this point in the code?

Thank you in advance!